# How add poDoNotEncode to TRUE from code in delphi

Tags: rest, delphi-xe

Is it possible and how add poDoNotEncode to TRUE from code in delphi.
eg.

```
with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
begin
     Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
     name:='Authorization';
     value:= l_authorization;
     //set poDoNotEncode  to TRUE here
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`TRESTRequestParameter.Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter.Options) property:

```pascal
with RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem do
begin
  Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
  Name := 'Authorization';
  Value := l_authorization;
  Options := Options + [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode];
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also try a shorter version of Remy's answer:

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Authorization', l_authorization).Options := [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode];
```

Not sure why one would use += style there btw, does the Param have some default options set for that property?

Comment: speacking of += style, for sets see here how you'd implement it (unfortunately no += for them and Include doesn't work on properties so would need to assign to separate variable first, then include, then copy back